# Dynamic data MySQL pivot issue

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I have the following tables:

- `Question (id, question)`
- `Answer (id, answer, qId, sess)`
- `Answer.qId = Question.id`,

The output from the query I would like (based on data below), would be:

```
+----+-----+------+
|sess|Color|Shape | 
+----+-----+------+
|ses1|green|square| 
|ses2|black|square| 
|ses3|black|circle|
+----+-----+------+
```

The 'sess' (meaning session) being `Answer.sess`, the other columns should be generated from the `Question.question` table.

I will not know the values/amount of rows for the 'question' table, and these may change. So I'm not able to hard code a query. I do believe this can be done using prepared statements. I've seen some prepared statements as answers on stackflow for similar questions, but are either one table, or the values are part of the question table, either way I can't seem to crack it!

Example schema/data:

```
CREATE TABLE answer
(`id` int, `answer` varchar(16), `qId` int, `sess` varchar(15));

INSERT INTO answer
(`id`, `answer`, `qId`, `sess`)
VALUES
(1, 'green', 1, 'ses1'),
(2, 'square', 2, 'ses1'),
(3, 'black', 1, 'ses2'),
(4, 'square', 2, 'ses2'),
(5, 'black', 1, 'ses3'),
(6, 'circle', 2, 'ses3');

CREATE TABLE question
(`id` int, `question` varchar(10));

INSERT INTO question
(`id`, `question`)
VALUES
(1, 'Color'),
(2, 'Shape');
```

Comment: This question should have bluefeet prints all over it.

Comment: This can be done using MySQL's prepared statements and a sproc, but surely far simpler to handle display logic at the application level/presentation layer assuming that's available.

Comment: Maybe this can help:
http://stratosprovatopoulos.com/web-development/mysql/pivot-table-with-dynamic-columns/

Comment: While this is a duplicate - here is a sql fiddle with some sample queries to help solve it. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c633c/3